# How to add a required dateSubmitted on the server with Meteor autoform?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I've got a Posts collection and the `dateSubmitted` field needs to be required. However, the value for this field should be generated on the server using server time.

```
Posts.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    optional: false
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    optional: false
  },
  dateSubmitted: {
    type: Date,
    optional: false
  }
}));
```

The problem with this is that the form won't submit on the client if I only have values for `title` and `content`. But I also *can't* insert it into the collection without a `dateSubmitted` value that is generated from the server.

I looked at the Autoform hooks and nothing seems to work in this case.

This is my desired workflow:

1. Schema says `title`, `content`, and `dateSubmitted` are required.
2. The client submits the form successfully with only `title` and `content`.
3. The server adds `dateSubmitted`
4. The new document then gets inserted into the collection.
   4.a. If for some reason the `dateSubmitted` can't be generated, an error gets sent back to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're already using [aldeed:collection2](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/collection2) then in your schema use the following:

```
dateSubmitted: {
    type: Date,
    autoValue: function(){
      if ( this.isInsert ) return new Date();
      else if ( this.isUpsert ) return { $setOnInsert: new Date };
      else if ( this.isSet ) this.unset();
    }
  }
```

This will automatically set the date on insert/upsert and then reject all later changes.

From http://0rocketscience.blogspot.com/2015/07/meteor-security-no-2-all-praise-aldeed.html

Comment: Thanks, corrected. To camelCase or not to camelcase, that is always the question...